# Resilience4J Retry not auto-configured in Spring boot 3

Tags: spring, spring-boot, resilience4j, resilience4j-retry

I'm in the process of migrating to Spring Boot 3. In Spring Boot 2 Resilience4J Retry was auto-configured and worked out of the box using the following setup:

application.yaml:

```
resilience4j.retry:
  instances:
    some-instance
      # retry config here
```

Test class:

```java
@SpringBootTest
public class TestClass {

  @Autowired
  private RetryRegistry retryRegistry;

  @Test
  void someTest() {
    // perform test and evaluate retries using retryRegistry
  }
}
```

However while updating to Spring Boot 3 using the following versions:

```
org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:3.0.0:compile
io.github.resilience4j:resilience4j-spring-boot2:jar:1.7.0:compile (derived from a Spring BoM)
```

The test in which the RetryRegistry was autowired failed with the following message:

```
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'retryRegistry': 
No qualifying bean of type 'io.github.resilience4j.retry.RetryRegistry' available:
expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate.
Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

I managed to fix the test by explicitly importing the Resilience4j Retry configuration in the test using:

```java
@Import(io.github.resilience4j.retry.autoconfigure.RetryAutoConfiguration.class)
```

However, I'm wondering why the component scanning mechanism in Spring Boot 3 did not pick up the retry config in the first place. Would anyone know why Spring Boot 3 did not pick up the class during component scanning?

Comment: You are using `resilience4j-spring-boot2` which, as the name implies is for Spring Boot 2. Whereas you should be using `resilience4j-spring-boot3` which will pull in the proper versions. When upgrading to Spring Boot 3, due to the breaking changes, you also need to update libraries you are using. afaik Resillience4j isn't managed by Spring so that manageme3nt comes from somewhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that it is related to a new META-INF file being used instead of the old `spring.factories` file. From the [documentation](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-3.0.0-M5-Release-Notes#auto-configuration-registration) :

> Spring Boot 2.7 introduced a new META-INF/spring/org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfiguration.imports file for registering auto-configurations, while maintaining backwards compatibility with registration in spring.factories. With this release, support for registering auto-configurations in spring.factories has been removed in favor of the imports file.

The Resilience4J dependency used in the `spring-cloud-dependencies-parent` BoM still uses a `spring.factories` file instead of the new file named `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfiguration.imports`. The new file has recently been introduced in Resilience4J ([source](https://github.com/resilience4j/resilience4j/commit/48ca2c8130bde3974d3d8c39923eb456b2b25834)).

Overriding the version from the Spring BoM with version `2.0.2` for all the resilience dependencies fixed it for me. I will check in a few days whether the new Resilience4J version has been updated in the Spring BoM (or resilience4j-spring-boot3 has been introduced).

[edit]
As others have noticed,`resilience4j-spring-boot3` is already available. I'll start using it.

Answer (score 1):

In the resilience4j project they changed the dependency for spring boot 3.

So you should go for io.github.resilience4j:resilience4j-spring-boot3:${resilience4jVersion}

like

```
org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:3.0.0:compile
io.github.resilience4j:resilience4j-spring-boot3:jar:2.0.0:compile
```

from the [documentation](https://resilience4j.readme.io/docs/getting-started-3)